# Regarding dynamic where clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @tbl_WhereClause AS TABLE (
    SearchField VARCHAR(255),
    Operator VARCHAR(25),
    ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),
    MatchCase BIT,
    TableName VARCHAR(MAX)   
)

DECLARE @WhereClause_XML XML
SET @WhereClause_XML = 
'<NewDataSet> 
  <param>
   <SearchField>EmployeeID</SearchField>
   <FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
   <ConditionData>201</ConditionData>
   <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
   <Table>Employee</Table>
 </param>
 <param>  
   <SearchField>DeptID</SearchField>
   <FilterCondition> = </FilterCondition>
   <ConditionData>AC01</ConditionData>
   <MatchCase>1</MatchCase>
   <Table>Department</Table>
 </param>
 <param>  
   <SearchField>Dob</SearchField>
   <FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
   <ConditionData>20120104</ConditionData>
   <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
   <Table>Employee</Table>
 </param>
</NewDataSet>'

INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData,  MatchCase,TableName)
SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField,
    A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator,
    A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
    A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,
    A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)

SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause
```

How can I join with the system table for each field to get the each field data type and show. please run the script and do the necessary changes in SQL. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to verify tables and columns, and to bring its types with their properties:

```
DECLARE @tbl_WhereClause AS TABLE (
SearchField VARCHAR(255),
Operator VARCHAR(25),
ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),
MatchCase BIT,
TableName VARCHAR(MAX),
Validity VARCHAR(100),
ColumnType VARCHAR(128),
ColumnPrecision INT,
ColumnScale INT,
ColumnNullable bit
)

DECLARE @WhereClause_XML XML
SET @WhereClause_XML = '
<NewDataSet>
<param>
<SearchField>EmployeeID</SearchField>
<FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
<ConditionData>201</ConditionData>
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
<Table>Employee</Table>
</param>
<param>  
<SearchField>DeptID</SearchField>
<FilterCondition> = </FilterCondition>
<ConditionData>AC01</ConditionData>
<MatchCase>1</MatchCase>
<Table>Department</Table>
</param>
<param>  
<SearchField>Dob</SearchField>
<FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
<ConditionData>20120104</ConditionData>
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
<Table>Employee</Table>
</param>
</NewDataSet>'

INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData,  MatchCase,TableName, Validity, ColumnType, ColumnPrecision, ColumnScale, ColumnNullable)
SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField,
    A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator,
    A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
    A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,
    A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName,
    CASE WHEN t.NAME+c.NAME IS NULL THEN 'invalid' ELSE 'valid' END ,
    ty.NAME,
    c.PRECISION,
    c.Scale,
    c.Is_Nullable
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)
LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON t.name = A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )
LEFT JOIN sys.COLUMNS c ON T.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID AND c.name = A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' )
LEFT JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id 

SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution.

```
/*        
--XML DATA SAMPLE        
DECLARE @xmlvar xml      
SET @xmlvar='      
<NewDataSet>      
  <param>      
    <SearchField>JID</SearchField>      
    <FilterCondition>%</FilterCondition>      
    <ConditionData>4000</ConditionData>      
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>      
    <Table>BBAJobs</Table>      
  </param>      
  <param>      
    <SearchField>Specialist</SearchField>      
    <FilterCondition>=</FilterCondition>      
    <ConditionData>Nigel Graham</ConditionData>      
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>      
    <Table>BBAJobs</Table>      
  </param>      
</NewDataSet>'        
exec GenericSearch 'JobAdder','vwAdvSrch',@xmlvar,'AND'      
*/        

--For generic search        

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenericSearch]        
(        
 @ModuleName VARCHAR(100),        
 @ViewName VARCHAR(100),        
 @WhereClause_XML XML,        
 @LogicalOperator VARCHAR(3)        
)        
AS        

BEGIN   
DECLARE @pop varchar(max)      
SET @pop='not true'        

DECLARE @SearchField VARCHAR(255),        
@Operator VARCHAR(25),        
@ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),        
@MatchCase BIT,        
@TableName VARCHAR(MAX),        
@Validity VARCHAR(100),        
@ColumnType VARCHAR(128),        
@ColumnPrecision INT,        
@ColumnScale INT,        
@ColumnNullable bit,        
@WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX),        
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)        


DECLARE @tbl_WhereClause AS TABLE         
(        
 SearchField VARCHAR(255),        
 Operator VARCHAR(25),        
 ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),        
 MatchCase BIT,        
 TableName VARCHAR(MAX),        
 Validity VARCHAR(100),        
 ColumnType VARCHAR(128),        
 ColumnPrecision INT,        
 ColumnScale INT,        
 ColumnNullable bit        
)        


INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData,  MatchCase,TableName,         
Validity, ColumnType, ColumnPrecision, ColumnScale, ColumnNullable)        

SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField,        
    A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator,        
    A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,        
    A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,        
    A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName,        
    CASE WHEN t.NAME+c.NAME IS NULL THEN 'invalid' ELSE 'valid' END ,        
    ty.NAME,        
    c.PRECISION,        
    c.Scale,        
    c.Is_Nullable        
 FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)        
 LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON t.name = A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )        
 LEFT JOIN sys.COLUMNS c ON T.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID AND c.name = A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' )        
 LEFT JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id         

SET @WhereClause= ' WHERE 1=1'        
SET @SQL = ''        
DECLARE SearchCursor CURSOR FOR         
SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause        

OPEN SearchCursor        

FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor         
INTO @SearchField, @Operator,@ConditionData,@MatchCase,@TableName,@Validity,@ColumnType,@ColumnPrecision,@ColumnScale,@ColumnNullable        

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
BEGIN        

 IF CHARINDEX('INT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN      
 SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END  
 ---new 
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('NTEXT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as nvarchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as nvarchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as nvarchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN      
     SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as nvarchar(max)) + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
  ELSE IF CHARINDEX('VARCHAR', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN      
     SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
  ELSE IF CHARINDEX('NVARCHAR', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN      
     SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + CAST(@SearchField as varchar(max)) + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
 ---new      
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('NUMERIC', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN      
     SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('BIT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN    
  IF CHARINDEX('TRUE', UPPER(@ConditionData)) > 0         
  BEGIN      
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+'1'        
  END      
  ELSE IF CHARINDEX('FALSE', UPPER(@ConditionData)) > 0         
  BEGIN      
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+'0'        
  END      
  ELSE      
  BEGIN      
   SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
     END      
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('DECIMAL', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0  
 BEGIN       
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN        
 SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END        
 END      
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('FLOAT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN        
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN        
 SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('REAL', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN 
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN        
 SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData       
   END       
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('MONEY', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN       
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE      
   BEGIN        
 SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData        
   END      
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('DATE', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN  
  SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + 'CONVERT(varchar,'+@SearchField+',112)' + space(1)+@Operator+'CONVERT(varchar,'''+@ConditionData+''',112)'        
 END        
 ELSE IF CHARINDEX('CHAR', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0         
 BEGIN       
  IF @MatchCase = 0        
  BEGIN        
   IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = 'S%'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+''''+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +'%'''        
   END        
   ELSE IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Operator)) = '%S'        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+' LIKE '+'''%'+REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''''        
   END        
   ELSE        
   BEGIN        
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+'''' + REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') + ''''        
   END        
  END        
  ELSE        
  IF @MatchCase = 1        
  BEGIN        
   SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + 'BINARY_CHECKSUM('+@SearchField+')' + space(1)+@Operator+'BINARY_CHECKSUM('''+ REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') +''')'        
  END        
 END         

 FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor         
 INTO @SearchField, @Operator,@ConditionData,@MatchCase,@TableName,@Validity,@ColumnType,@ColumnPrecision,@ColumnScale,@ColumnNullable        
END        

CLOSE SearchCursor          
DEALLOCATE SearchCursor         

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + FieldName + ' as [' + FieldDesc + '], ' FROM SearchMaster WHERE ModuleName = @ModuleName        
SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+ left(@SQL, len(RTRIM(LTRIM(@SQL)))-1) + ' FROM '+ @ViewName        
SET @SQL = @SQL + @WhereClause     

--exec sp_executesql @SQL        
exec(@SQL)        
--select @SQL  
--PRINT @SQL        
END
```